# Adding view from external library to xml layout

Tags: android-layout

I try to make xml layout with view from external library. In java code I add this library by

```
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView;
```

so in xml file I tried

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

but I get error caused by inflating this view. How should I add MapView to FrameLayout to make it working? I would by grateful for help.

Comment: did you make a google api project ?

Comment: I didn't, where can I find it?

Comment: you are using eclipse right? when you create the project select google api

Comment: I don't have option like this, I have ApiDemos, is it this same?

Comment: are you trying to do this? http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapView

Comment: I'm sorry to say I don't see the solution on that page. I've already searched there.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I think that answering to this question may help others that may have the same question.

In your XML layout file:

```
    <org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity class:

1- Your Activity class must extend org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapActivity

```
public class FaramapActivity extends MapActivity {
    MapView mapView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_screen);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMapFile(new File("/path/to/file/on/sd_card"));
        mapView.getController().setZoom(12);
    }
}
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```